# How to calculate column averaged kinetic energy?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere

I have u-wind, v-wind and w-wind at 11 pressure levels (starting from 1000 to 100). I would like to calculate column averaged kinetic energy. I have the formula to do this as:

$KE=\frac 1{g(Ps-Ptop)} $$
\int_{Ptop}^{Ps}\frac 12(u^2+v^2+w^2)dp$

My question is how to use this formula to compute column averaged kinetic energy? Can I do it simply as follows:

$KE=\frac 1{9.8(1000-100)}\frac12[ \sum_{Ptop}^{Ps}(u^2+v^2+w^2)] $

Where the [ ] is the sum of  $u^2+v^2+w^2$ at all 11 pressure levels

Comment: you are looking at integration and specifically numerically integration.